# ¿Cómo reemplazar una línea(Texto) en un archivo con PowerShell?

Tags: windows, script, powershell, chrome

Compañeros Tengo que actualizar una URL en los marcadores de Google Chrome modificando el archivo llamado Bookmarks
El siguiente codigo que les comparto deberia realizar el cambio pero cada vez que ejecuto el script, este se ejecuta correctamente pero no realiza ningún cambio.

Comparto el código, agradezco el apoyo.

```
function lin
{$input | Select-String '.' | Select-Object LineNumber, Line}

$Numln = (Get-Content .\Bookmarks | sls -Pattern '"Color Palette",' | lin)
$Oper = $Numln.LineNumber - 5
$linraw = (Get-Content .\Bookmarks -TotalCount $Oper)[-1]
$val = '"url": "https://new-url.com"'
(Get-Content .\Bookmarks) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$linraw","$val" } | Set-Content .\Bookmarks
```

Comment: Tienes permisos para cambiar el archivo? Lo ejecutas cuando el navegador está ejecutándose?

Comment: El script se corre con permisos de Administrador.
Antes de realizar cualquier cambio en el Bookmarks se crea un backup en C:\Temp y desde aqui se realiza la modificacion.

Comment: No es claro si el archivo físicamente permanece sin cambios o intentas usarlo y chrome lo muestra como antes. Si es lo segundo, hay que recordar que chrome mantiene un Bookmarks.bak y que debes revisar el [formato](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Chrome_bookmarks) de los datos que estás poniendo en el archivo modificado. Si es lo primero, luego me paso a windows e intento replicarlo :)

Comment: Una disculpa por no haberme explicado bien, el script completo realiza lo siguiente.
1.- Primero se realiza una copia del archivo Bookmarks en C:\Temp
2.- Estando, PowerShell ubicado en C:\Temp, este aplica los cambios en el archivo Bookmarks copiado 
3.- Realizado el cambio PowerShell regresa el archivo Bookmarks a su carpeta original y si en ese momento Chrome está abierto abría que cerrar el navegador y volverlo a abrir para poder visualizar los cambios en los marcadores.
la estructura de un marcador dentro de Bookmarks es la siguiente

Comment: {
            "date_added": "13171482946701142",
            "guid": "09485371-7286-4e46-ac7b-2edf32c6edb7",
            "id": "159",
            "name": "DENWA UC / Firmwares",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.denwaip.com/es/firmwares.html"
         }
la parte que se desea modificar es “url”, hace unos días utilice el mismo script para agregar un marcador nuevo y no tuve problemas, funciono correctamente.
Y en este momento utilizando el mismo script para remplazar la línea de la url tengo el problema de que no Scribe nada.